# how to count how many times a while statment has run php and sql

Tags: php, sql, count, while-loop

Hi I am trying to find out how many times that my while statement has run but I have no clue how to do this the reason i need to know this is to see how many rows have been output to my screen and then just display a message to the screen once it has found the number. my code is pretty long. sorry about poor English thanks in advance.

```
<?php
            try {
                    $serverName = "127.0.0.0.0";
                    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"uid", "PWD"=>"pwd");
                    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
                    if( $conn === false ) 
                    {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT TOP 10 [company]
                            ,[partnum]
                            ,[description]
                            FROM [database].[uid].[table]
                            WHERE Part.partnum LIKE ? or Part.description LIKE ?";          
                    /* Set parameter values. */
                    $params = array(  "%" . str_replace(" ","%",$_POST["part"] ). "%", "%" . str_replace(" ","%",$_POST["part"] ) . "%");

                    $x = true;
                    /*echo print_r($params, true);*/
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );

                    if( $stmt === false) 
                    {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                    }

                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
                    {

                        if($x == true)
                        {               
                        echo"<form action=\"locations.php\" method=\"post\">";
                            echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"part\" id=\"3\" value=\"".$row['partnum']."\">";
                            echo"<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"lon1\" id=\"1\" value=\"".$_POST["lon1"]."\">";
                            echo"<input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"lat1\" id=\"2\" value=\"".$_POST["lat1"]."\">";
                        echo"<button type=\"submit\">";
                        echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                                echo $row['partnum']."<br/>";
                        echo "</div>";  
                                echo"<img style=\"width:50%;\"; src=\"productimages/".$row['partnum'].".jpg\" alt=\"Save icon\" onError=\"this.src='productimages/noimage.jpg'\"/>";
                        echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                                echo $row['description'];
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo"</button>";
                        echo"</form>";

                            }   

                    }

                    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
                }   catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                }   
            ?>
```

Comment: OOOW Sorry you are already using $x. Ok I editted my answer. I used $a instead of $x now... srry didn't notice you were already using $x but my answer should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{

    if($x == true)
    {               
    echo"<form action=\"locations.php\" method=\"post\">";
        echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"part\" id=\"3\" value=\"".$row['partnum']."\">";
        echo"<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"lon1\" id=\"1\" value=\"".$_POST["lon1"]."\">";
        echo"<input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"lat1\" id=\"2\" value=\"".$_POST["lat1"]."\">";
    echo"<button type=\"submit\">";
    echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
            echo $row['partnum']."<br/>";
    echo "</div>";  
            echo"<img style=\"width:50%;\"; src=\"productimages/".$row['partnum'].".jpg\" alt=\"Save icon\" onError=\"this.src='productimages/noimage.jpg'\"/>";
    echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
            echo $row['description'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo"</button>";
    echo"</form>";

        }   
    $i++;
}

echo $i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a variable in while.
It increments its value for every loop (you can use instead of while statement the for statement, so you've got free a counter variable).

If you need to know every result of iteration, please put at the end of the loop an output command to show on your screen the result you want.

I hope I accomplish your task. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: could you show me an example of this ?? im fairly new to php and sql

Answer (score 0):

just declare one variable before while loop like($inc=0;) and increment it inside while loop like($inc++;) .Now you can use this variable to get count of while loop run.

Comment: this returned back the number 0 even thou there was 10 records output

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$a=0

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
      $a=$a+1;
}
echo "you have {$a} records"
```

Comment: this was a nice answer very small and worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
                $whileCounter = 1;

                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
                {

                    if($x == true)
                    {               
                    echo"<form action=\"locations.php\" method=\"post\">";
                        echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"part\" id=\"3\" value=\"".$row['partnum']."\">";
                        echo"<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"lon1\" id=\"1\" value=\"".$_POST["lon1"]."\">";
                        echo"<input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"lat1\" id=\"2\" value=\"".$_POST["lat1"]."\">";
                    echo"<button type=\"submit\">";
                    echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                            echo $row['partnum']."<br/>";
                    echo "</div>";  
                            echo"<img style=\"width:50%;\"; src=\"productimages/".$row['partnum'].".jpg\" alt=\"Save icon\" onError=\"this.src='productimages/noimage.jpg'\"/>";
                    echo "<div style=\"font-family:verdana;color:#3083FF;font-size:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;\">";
                            echo $row['description'];
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo"</button>";
                    echo"</form>";
                    $whileCounter++;
                    echo $whileCounter;
                        }   
                }
```

If you want the counter to start where it left off to see the total counts after several while loops,
simply put:

```
$whileCounter = 1;
```

As declaration on the top instead of in the code that gets called every time.

Comment: Though change 1 to 0 or swap $whileCounter++ and echo $whileCounter

Comment: this worked perfect as well it just shows a number for each time it loops so it loops ten times you get 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 on the page instead of just one number but thanks this really helped

Comment: To test how many times it runs it's best to show the number for every time it loops do that possible mistakes can be found. For example, when you get 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 there's most likely an error somewhere causing a miscount. This would mean the while ran 9 times since it skipped one due to an unreported error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 0;

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $x++; //$x is now how many times this loop has run.
        //eg when it's set to 2 this is the 2nd time
        //the while loop has ran

  // Rest of your code here
}
```

This is what you need. `$x` will be incremented by one on each loop